# Get pid of last started instance of a certain process

Tags: linux, bash

I have several instances of a certain process running and I want to determine the process id of the one that has been started last.
So far I came to this code:

```
ps -aef | grep myProcess | grep -v grep | awk -F" " '{print $2}' |
while read line; do
  echo $line
done
```

This gets me all process ids of myProcess. Somehow I need to compare now the running times of this pids and find out the one with the smallest running time. But I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Thank you a lot... pgrep does the job in just one line of code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier way would be to use `pgrep` with its `-n, --newest` switch.

> Select only the newest (most recently started) of the matching
>   processes.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `pgrep`, you can use `ps` and sort by start time:

```
ps -ef kbsdstart
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep). It has a  `-n` (newest) option for that. So just try

```
pgrep -n myProcess
```